# Cocos2d simulator / device framerate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

I just started learning cocos2d for iPhone and the framerate problem hit me.
I see the framerate drop sometimes to 30 fps on the simulator but on my iPhone 5 it runs at 60 fps.
So I was wondering, will it cause me any problems on other devices? (4, 4S)

Comment: There is some discussion of this on the cocos2d forum: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/very-low-fps-on-ipad-simulator/

Comment: Never measure performance on simulator, especially for graphics-heavy app.

Comment: Simulator does software emulation of some OpenGL ES shader capabilities etc, so do not trust it a lot about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPS (Frames per second) depends on device's hardware capability.So when you are running on simulator or old version iOS device. You will get 30 FPS.

By default FPS is 60.

So, You are on right track.

Good Luck !!!